# Modular settings/config

Tags: wpf, prism, app-config, settings.settings

I have a modular application created with PRISM 4. My main WPF application.desktop solution has an app.config and my sysAdmin module has app.config and a settings file.

Can anyone tell me how I can edit the sysAdmin modules' config/settings files as they seem to be wrapped up in the sysAdmin.dll??????

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... hopefully the interfaces are defined in a commonly referenced assembly?  If so, then just `UnityContainer.Resolve<T>()` the interface that contract-binds the class which exposes the config/settings that you require.

That's how I'd do it, from a naive point of view. Once we get into more complicated factors, this would change, but I'm not sure exactly what your setup is.

Comment: Sorry, probably not explained very well. I want my setup team/engineers to be able to manually amend the settings or app.config file for modules upon installing at client sites. I can see my main app.config for WPF application, but any modules config files do not get deployed "out of dll" if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to make my modules' app.config visible upon deployment so I added my settings which I needed to be editable upon client machines to the app.config of main WPF application then added a "sharedInfo" class in my Infrastructure module and populated this upon loading the main app from the main app.config so I can access the values in my module. Not ideal but works for me.